# Vba VLookup from another worksheet on VBA on cell change

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have some data validation on Column D, and when option 1 is chosen, it should run a makro that vlookup another sheet in the same file and input data in column G (same row).

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(True, True) = Sheets("SERVICES BREAKDOWN").Range("$D$15") Then
        Select Case Target
            Case "ORIGIN CHARGE"
              Sheets("SERVICES BREAKDOWN").Range("$G$15").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("SERVICES BREAKDOWN").Range("$D$15"), Sheets("INITIAL").Range("D15:K22"), 4, False)
                      Case Else
                'Do nothing
        End Select
    End If
```

This code wont return an error , still it does nothing, anyone can guess how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Target.Address(True, True) = Sheets("SERVICES BREAKDOWN").Range("$D$15")`

Is going to try to compare the value in D15 to the address of target and unless D15 has its own address in it, this will never be true.

`Range().Address` returns a string, so use:

```
If Target.Address(1,1) = "$D$15" then
```

Or as is popular:

```
If Not Intesect(Target,Range("$D$15")) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: Should I input : 'Target.Address(1,1) = "$D$15" ' before the Select Case?